# ¿Que són los métodos abstractos?

Tags: java, clase-abstracta

> *David J. Barnes, Michael Kölling (2007). Programación orientada a objetos con Java Una introducción práctica usando BlueJ (3.ª ed.)*
>
> ### **10.4 Más métodos abstractos**
>
> … .En Java, los campos se manejan de manera diferente que los métodos:
>   los campos no pueden ser sobrescritos por las versiones de las
>   subclases.
>
> ...
>
> Esta regla se aplica independientemente de si un campo es estático o no.

Entonces, los campos simplemente de heredan y los métodos se sobrescriben...¿Es correcto?

Comment: Sería interesante [edit] para señalar dónde se encuentra este párrafo, así como cuál es tu interpretación. Un título más descriptivo ya sería para matrícula :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se refiere a que los metodos de una superclase pueden ser sobreescritos en una subclase, modificando el comportamiento de dicho método mediante `@Override`

Los campos (atributos, miembros, de una clase) no pueden ser sobreescritos, se heredan.

Si tienes por ejemplo:

```
public class SuperType{
    protected String name;
}

public class SubType extends SuperType{
    private String name;
}
```

El campo `name` de la clase `SubType` no es una sobreescritura del campo `name` de la clase `SuperType`, simplemente son dos campos diferentes. Parado en SubType tu puedes acceder mediante:

```
super.name //corresponde al campo name de SuperType
this.name //corresponde al campo name de SubType
name //corresponde al campo name de SubType
```

¨

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la respuesta lleva un tiempo publicada y aceptada; por añadir algo más sobre las métodos abstractos:

El propósito de un método abstracto es dejar que las clases que heredan de éstas puedan implementar un método de diferentes maneras. Este mecanismo es fundamental para hacer uso del polimorfismo, uno de los conceptos principales de la programación orientada a objetos, así como la mayoría de patrones de diseño más usados.

Te voy a poner un ejemplo con un circo, en la que hay artistas como malabaristas, payasos tragafuegos. Cada uno de estos artistas saluda, hace su número y se despide.

Empezamos a hacer la clase artista, con el método saludar y despedir (todos los artistas lo hacen de la misma manera.

```
public class Artista {

   public void saludar() {
      System.out.println("Saludo");
   }

   public void actuar() {
      System.out.println("Despedida");
   }

}
```

Hasta aquí vamos bien, pero ahora tenemos que implementar la forma en que actúa cada artista, y esto no lo podemos saber hasta que sepamos de que artista estamos hablando.

Por lo que podemos decir que el método para actuar sea abstracto y dejar(obligar) que sus clases hijas sean las que implementen el método.

```
public abstract class Artista {

   public void saludar() {
      System.out.println("Saludo");
   }

   public void despedirse() {
      System.out.println("Despedida");
   }

   public abstract void actuar();

}
```

Ahora podemos definir las clases hijas, solo necesitamos implementar en principio los métodos abstractos ya que se heredan los métodos de la clase padre.

```
public class Payaso extends Artista {

   @Override
   public void actuar() {
      System.out.println("Hago el número del payaso");
   }

}

public class Tragafuegos extends Artista {

   @Override
   public void actuar() {
      System.out.println("Hago el número del tragafuegos");
   }

}
```

Ahora que tenemos nuestro circo montado podemos dar comienzo a la actuación:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Artista> artistas = new ArrayList<>();
   artistas.add(new Payaso());
   artistas.add(new Tragafuegos());
   for (Artista artista: artistas) {
      artista.saludar();
      artista.actuar();
      artista.despedirse();
   }
}
```

Salida:

```
Saludo
Hago el número del payaso
Despedida
Saludo
Hago el número del tragafuegos
Despedida
```

Fíjate que aquí creamos una lista de artistas y vamos creando artistas de diferentes tipos, en este caso un payaso y un tragafuegos. Cada uno de los artistas saludará, actuará y se despedirá. En el bucle for **no sabemos hasta que estemos ejecutando ese código** de que tipo exactamente es el artista (solo sabemos que es un hijo de la clase Artista).

Cuando se ejecute el método saludar y el método despedirse, se ejecutarán los métodos correspondientes de la clase Artista, pero cuando se ejecute el método actuar, **se ejecutará el método de la clase que corresponda en función del tipo de artista sobre el que estemos iterando**.

Llegados a este punto te puedes preguntar, ¿y esto mismo no se puede hacer con un if, consultando el tipo de cada artista? Algo así:

```
for (Artista: artista) {
  artista.saludar();
  if (artista.tipo.equals("Payaso")) {
    System.out.println("Actuación del payaso");
  } else if (artista.tipo.equals("Tragafuegos")) {
    System.out.println("Actuación del tragafuegos");
  }
  artista.despedirse();
}
```

El problema de esto es que conforme crece la aplicación vas a encontrarte que repites muchas veces ese if, con lo que puedes introducir errores de copia/pega. Además, si tienes el código lleno de esos ifs, que pasa si te llega un nuevo artista: El funambulista. Tendrías que ir a todos los ifs a añadir esa condición para que tu aplicación no falle.

Por último, hay que tener en cuenta que al añadir un método abstracto a una clase se producen dos efectos:

- La clase que estás definiendo debe pasar a ser abstracta, y por lo tanto no se va a poder instanciar con new. Esto es porque si no defines un método, ¿qué pasaría si creases un objeto de esa clase y el método no estuviese definido?
- Inmediatamente **obligas** a las clases que hereden de esta, a que implementen ese método o que lo marquen como abstracto (haciendo que a su vez esa clase pase a ser abstracta).

Especialmente interesante ese obligas, ya que utilizando con cabeza los métodos abstractos, puedes influir en la forma en que se reutilicen las clases.

Imagínate que tienes una clase que genera un informe muy complejo y lo guarda en un fichero DOC. Sabes que otro programador va a tener que hacer lo mismo pero va a tener que guardarlo en un PDF. Quieres que la generación del informe se haga de la misma forma pero que únicamente se cambie la forma en que se guarda el resultado. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
public abstract class GeneradorInformes {

  private DatosInforme obtenerDatosInforme() {
    // Método muy complejo que no quiero que se modifique.
  }

  public void generarInforme() {
     DatosInforme datos = obtenerDatosInforme(); // NO QUIERO QUE SE CAMBIE ESTO
     escribirResultado(datos);
  }

  protected abstract escribirResultado(DatosInforme datos);

}

public class GeneradorInformesDOC extends GeneradorInformes {

  @Override
  public escribirResultado(DatosInforme datos) {
    // Escribo un fichero DOC con los datos.
  }

}
```

Si orientas los métodos de esta manera, el que quiera generar un informe en otro formato como PDF, HTML, etc, solo tendrá que crear una clase que extienda de GeneradorInformes, y estará obligado a implementar el método de escribirResultado. Esa persona no necesitará conocer como se genera el informe ni necesitará realizar modificaciones en ese método.

Comment: Tienes un error importante: las clases abstractas **no se pueden instanciar**, y tú lo haces en la actuación de circo. Normalmente las clases abstractas sirven para ofrecer una implementación parcial de un contrato de una interfaz sin forzar algunos puntos clave. Pero al no implementar el contrato completamente, instanciarlas violaría las reglas de POO de que todas las clases deben adherirse a los contratos que implementan. Por eso las clases abstractas no se pueden instanciar y obligan a su vez a sus subclases a implementar sus métodos abstractos.

Comment: @DavidDPG Cierto, ha sido error de copia y pega, ya está editado. De hecho hacía esa mención a que no se pueden instanciar un poco más adelante